# How to grab the result string of a server side function to update an image src on the web page in rails 3?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, prototypejs

Ok, I am totally new to that Ajax thing... and I need some help to get started.

Basically what I am trying to do is rather simple I believe. I got a select which is used to select a topic. To each topic I have associated in the db a bunch of images (10 per topic). What I am trying to do, is when the drop-down is changed to refresh the images with a random one taken from the list corresponding to the selected topics.

What I gather from my research is that I need to call a remote_function to my controller with the topic selected as a parameter and execute the function to get that new img path and replace the old path with the new one on the page.

The problem is that I have absolutely no clue how to get started on this ?

I am using Rails 3.0.3, and the default Ajax library: Prototype.